# create API and Control panel in two separate project

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, lumen

if i want to create Restful Api with control panel (same database and table), can i create C Panel with laravel, and API with another laravel project or Lumen? it is best way? if it is possible, what about (storage), how can i make it shared between this two project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel you can have /api routes and web routes. So, you could use the same project if you want to avoid unnecessary complexity if it's not needed. Not sure of your app idea, but you can definitely do it with one Laravel project which would make things much easier if your project doesn't require separate applications for front end and api.

In the /routes directory of your Laravel project you have api.php (routes prefixed with API by default) and your web.php which is where your web routes can live.

Comment: Thank you, yes i know that, but some programmers advice me to separate? i don't know if i can create a professional project with cpanel and API in same project? there's is no problem?

Comment: Personally, I believe you can create a professional project with API routes in the same project. It just depends on your use case and that is up to you to determine if you need a completely separate API. Is your API going to be public facing, etc. There are many things to think about with this, but I suggest only moving to a separate project when and if you need it.